# Calling Save Changes Multiple Times

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I was wondering if anyone has done any perf tests around the effect calling EF Cores SaveChangesAsync() has on performance if there are no changes to be saved.

Essentially I am assuming it's basically nothing and therefore isn't a big deal to call it "just in case"?

(I am trying to do something with tracking user activity in middleware in asp net core and essentially on the way out I want to make sure save changes was called to persist the activity to the database. There is a chance that it has already been called on the context depending on the operation of the user and if that's the case I don't want to incur the cost of a second operation when the activity could be persisted as part of the normal transaction/round trip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/9c642d3df13a6367d312bbd08a6c440fec012664/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/StateManager.cs) if there are no changes, nothing will be done. As far it has impact to performance, I don't know. But of course calling `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` without any changes will have a performance impact in relation to don't call them.

That's the same behavior like EF6 has too.